# What is the cosine distance of something and itself?

Tags: scipy, cosine-similarity

I'm playing with scipy's cosine distance. From what I've gathered, the closer a cosine distance is to 1, the more similar the vectors are. I got some unexpected results in a text mining project, so I decided to investigate the simplest case.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial
arr1 = np.array([1,1])
arr2 = np.array([1,1])
print scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(arr1, arr2)
```

My program prints 0.0.

Shouldn't the result be 1.0? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the cosine *distance*, not the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).  A basic requirement for a function d(u, v) to be a distance is that d(u, u) = 0.

See the definition of the formula in the docstring of [`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html), and notice that the formula begins `1 - (...)`.  Your expectation of the function is probably based on the quantity in `(...)`, but that expression is the cosine similarity.